# Unit tests terminated in Debug mode

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2 (Community Edition) under Windows 7 and Windows 10 Pro, Gradle 2.9, JDK 1.7.0_65. Operating systems installed as guests under VMware Workstation 11.1.3

I have created Android Gradle application with single empty activity and wanted to check how unit test support works. There is a single unit test module ApplicationTest.java created by IDE, it contains only constructor. Right-clicking on [java] folder I created 'All in Module' JUnit3 test configuration.

Tests complete successfully when I Run them, however fail if I Debug the configuration. Failure reason says 'Terminated' ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSCmS.png), [IDEA log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6r9Ag-ygMRaa2VBX0RLUFNhU0U/view?usp=sharing)) which explained in the documentation as 'Test terminated. This status is assigned to tests that were cancelled by clicking the Stop button'. Just want to confirm that I didn't click the Stop button.

Logcat logs don't report any failures, IDE log reports 2 tests passed too. However problem remains as IntelliJ still reports a termination.

Sometimes I also getting 'Test framework quit unexpectedly' error and no tests succeed.

I've done some research and found similar questions, no real solutions mentioned. Have strong suspicion that this is a configuration issue.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: see related https://stackoverflow.com/a/63678543/448779 - may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In my company's case, the fix was to:

1. Open `Edit Configuration...` for `All tests` (or whatever you renamed it into).
2. Switch to `Debugger` tab.
3. And finally, in `Debug mode` combo-box, select the `Java` option, because:

   - Although we have lots of Native codes,
     Android-studio 3.2.1 (which we were using) does not seem to support debugging both (but Java only mode works fine).

> **Note** that we've seen above since Android-studio 3.2.1 until Android-studio 2022.x, **but** above might not be required in some newer version.

Comment: Bro I am dealing with this issue for hours. I thought the crash is because of memory related. So I changed VM options, did many changes to increase memory usage. Found out that it wasn't the reason. Your suggestion just saved me. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Gabor's suggestion seemed to fix this issue for me. On a Mac (and I presume on a Windows machine, but with a different route to get there) go to Preferences:

From the menu bar at the top **Android Studio → Preferences**

*or*

Hit **⌘ and ,** to jump straight to it.

Then in the menu search box type "instant". Uncheck the box that says "Enable instant run..", which looks like the image below.

[image]

That fixed it for me; didn't even need to restart/kill ADB.

It seems to be enabled by default, and I use it often to hot-swap changes during development, so I didn't think to turn it off when running Espresso tests.

Comment: I'm not sure about corresponding option in Android Studio under Windows OS, however original question was about **IntelliJ IDEA**, which does not have "Instant Run" switch

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, the problem is solved by setting in the test's run configuration:
Shorten command line -> JAR manifest.

Answer (score -1):

To get rid of unit test problems in debug mode, I deleted all test folders in android studio explorer, then I commented three test implementation lines in build.gradle(module) file. Then I changed the combobox in android studio menu (top of the IDE) from "all in app" to "app".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/alPrS.png

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Please note that original question was about IntelliJ IDEA, so this solution is not applicable