# 'Ignoring InnerClasses attribute' warning turns to error after AS 2.0 update

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-espresso

I have been researching this problem all day since updating AS to 2.0 this morning and cant find any solutions.

When running espresso UI tests, this 'warning' shows up:

[image]

The error used to be a warning before upgrading AS.

The espresso UI tests can still run, but after they pass, AS reports that they have been terminated. I do not believe this issue is related to progaurd and I do not need to DEX. I have tried checking out the project fresh from git. (i was able to fix the duplicateFileException)

The problem: warning messages shows as an error, and UI tests 'terminate' after passing

[image]

You can see here the test passed but is terminated...

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750611/unit-tests-terminated-in-debug-mode - similar to this issue...i tried turning off instant run but it didnt work for me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553985/terminated-test-status-without-any-failure-message-in-android-studio-2-0-while-u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Test Terminated** issue is fixed in Android Studio 2.1. The update is available now. Also consider upgrading Android Gradle plugin to 2.1.0 if you have other issues.