# "Run app" runs my old project, not my current one

Tags: android-studio

I am beginning a course of Android Studio but i have problems running my code :
Indeed, when i click on "Run app", with a Nexus S API 22, it is my old project which is launched and not my new one. I have the Android Studio 3.5

I tried to restart Android Studio et start whole new projects but it wasn't successful.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you might want to add more info in here. So we can know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the application or clear the cache from settings.

If this doesn't help, try restarting the emulator **without** saving its state.

Answer (score 0):

First try running a new Basic Activity(File > New > New Project > Basic Activity), if it run the Basic Activity without problem. The problem probably is the file path of your project, the issues of copy pasting a project folder. Try hovering the mouse in your Program file Tab
[image]

confirm the file path if it is correct.

if it's correct check the run/debug configuration and set it to default.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer,

I have tried a Basic Activity but it still didn't work.
I hovered the file path, but i don't know to what path i should compare it to see if it's the good one ? Sorry haha
https://imgur.com/PZSARia

Comment: No problem in your file path. Now try checking Run > Edit Configuration then check the Launch Options > Launch = Default Activity and the Installation Options > Deploy = default APK.

Comment: If the problem persist try using another emulator or try it to the real device.

Comment: Hello, for whatever reasons, i started a new project (empty activity), made my project and ran it and it worked !
I just have an issue :
The emulator worked and showed my app, my button worked (it is supposed to write a "Button Clicked !" message in the log) but then, i closed it and reopened it but my button didn't work anymore.
I have this last message on my log :
"Error while waiting for device: Time out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online"

Here's a screenshot :/
https://imgur.com/jgfeLPQ

Comment: sometimes a simple copy paste of the problem in uncle google can solve your problem, refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675654/error-while-waiting-for-device-time-out-after-300seconds-waiting-for-emulator-t goodluck

Comment: Once again, i restarted it today and it worked. I really am confused on why it works one day and not the other, with the same technical context.. :/
Thank you for your help and your fast answers !