# Android Studio can't run AVD... times out

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, apple-m1

Just got a new M1 Mac Mini and I have been having trouble running my Android projects.

I'm using Android Studio (Bumblebee), JDK 11 (tried 17 as well), and Gradle 7.3.

When I try to run the project from AS, it builds fine and then gets stuck on "Waiting for target device to come online" and eventually times out.

[image: Android Studio]

If I try to run the emulator again I get a message that the device is already running, including a path to a lock file.

[image: AS Error Message]

However, I've found that if I run the emulator manually from the CLI, the emulator *does* open, at which point I *can* get AS to run the app on said emulator. So the problem is apparently just that AS can't *open* the AVD.

Command line output when running emulator via `adelphia$ emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_32_arm64-v8a`:

```
adelphia$ emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_32_arm64-v8a
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.6.0 (build_id 8100890) (CL:N/A)
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_new_posture_requested(int) ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_dismiss_posture_selection_dialog() ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_new_resizable_requested(PresetEmulatorSizeType) ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_dismiss_resizable_dialog() ((null):0, (null))
WARNING | cannot add library /Users/adelphia/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
INFO    | added library /Users/adelphia/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib
INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
INFO    | Sending adb public key [QAAAAG8XVkhVwEAAQA....= adelphia@unknown]
INFO    | Rootcanal has  been activated.
Could not initialize record - Unknown Audiodevice
Could not initialize record - Unknown Audiodevice
Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
qemu-system-aarch64: warning: opening audio input failed
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8556, security: Local
INFO    | Advertising in: /Users/adelphia/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/avd/running/pid_1469.ini
Could not initialize record - Unknown Audiodevice
Could not initialize record - Unknown Audiodevice
Failed to create voice `adc'
Could not initialize record - Unknown Audiodevice
Could not initialize record - Unknown Audiodevice
Failed to create voice `adc'
```

If it's relevant, here's my `.bash_profile` (changed back to bash)

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/adelphia/Scripts:$PATH"

export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh

export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.14.jdk/Contents/Home
```

So, how do I get AS to be able to open the emulator from the GUI?

Comment: Check these links It may help you - https://www.technipages.com/android-emulator-stuck-waiting-for-target-to-come-online,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675654/error-while-waiting-for-device-time-out-after-300seconds-waiting-for-emulator-t

Comment: Why are you ignoring that "Android Gradle Plugin can be updated" notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update tools for AVD in the IDE.
Android Emulator is **31.2.6**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Updating the emulator fixed this for me. Version 31.2.7 is out now.

Comment: @Geekygecko I guess you should set the answer as correct. It can help other users.

Comment: I have marked the answer with an up vote as useful but I can't mark it as correct as I didn't ask the question.