# JUnit5 Jupiter test terminated in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, junit5

When I run the my unit tests, they immediatly are being terminated. However no logging is presented. (only 'Failed to start' and 'Process finished with exit code 255').

Tests worked before...
JUnit 4 does not give me this problem.
Test do run succesfully in Maven.

I use JUnit5 Jupiter and IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 (Ultimate Edition).

Anyone any thoughts?

Comment: Please share the code sample. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same behaviour as described in this question. What fixed the problem for me was removing conflicting dependencies:

```
    Remove similar entries ->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

> as it is already included by spring-boot-starter-test. Removing the explicit dependency will enable SpringBoot to handle incompatible version issues between dependencies for you.

Answer (score 1):

`@Before` and `@After` no longer exist; use `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` instead.

`@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` no longer exist; use `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` instead.

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-tips

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.

The single thing that fixed this - and which I could reproduce - is this:
**don't .close() System.out** (or System.err).

```
@Test
void failure()
    {
    System.out.close();
    }
```

makes happen what you describe.

Wherever I passed System.out to functions that would .close() their OutputStream later, I replaced them with a new ByteArrayOutputStream()  instead.

Answer (score 0):

After experiencing the same, I've debugged only to find that tests are completely executing and all assertions pass.

I've managed to narrow the issue down to `System.out.println` call whose output is  somehow being held until all the tests are complete before, and eventually flushed, before IDEA gets to claim that test was interrupted.

Removing a reference to `System.out` from test code makes the tests go green in IDEA again.

Answer (score 0):

For me using `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` worked instead of `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll`

Comment: This answer is duplicated and missing reference